# Ubuntu sharing my Device's pieces of information, How can I stop it?

Tags: 22.10

The problem is when I attempt new login on my google account activities show my activities it is normal but when opening the activities popup it is showing my device name and model number, I have checked with another OS but another OS is just sharing the OS name not the model number, Is it possible to stop it as an ubuntu user?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: a new login from what program?

Comment: If that’s in the browser, you may want to check the User Agent string that’s being set. That’s browser-specific and not something related to Ubuntu 

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment, I am using the google chrome browser, You said this problem is not related to Ubuntu, But I want to clarify you when I am using Windows OS and google chrome this time That info not showing